# How to remove gray color effect when touch move using objective c

Tags: ios, iphone, colors, uiimage

I converted an image to fully gray when loaded, but I want to remove the gray color from it when touch move and view original image color.

I want to know how to convert from gray color effect to the original image and from original to gray when user moves finger over the image.

Comment: I beleive you have the original image stored in memory. What I would do to add two overlapping UIImageViews. The topmost would be the colored one and fully transparent. Then on touchDown event I would make a short animation in a fraction of a second to increase its alpha to 1.0. On touchUp event reverse it.

Comment: can you give me sample code sothat i can understand?

Comment: I want to add original color only where the touch move restof all will be gray .

Comment: So you have the idea have a "circle" to be colored at the area where you touch it? Or you want to have the full photo to be colored on touch?

Comment: A "circle" to be colored at the area where you touch it

Comment: A did a solution , but it is slow and give memory warning. That's why i need another idea

Comment: Bro,help me to solve this

Comment: Sorry I was afak. Still interested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is the following.

You need TWO UIImageViews. Add one on the other and make them to overlap pixel by pixel. You have two options:

1. B&W in foreground
2. Color in foreground

Both solutions fundamentally are the same. You need to use a mask on the topmost view. With a mask layer the white areas will be fully opaque, blacks are 100% transparent, grays are semi-transparent.

Example for the mask:

[image: Mask image]

```
 CALayer *maskLayer = [CALayer layer];
 UIImage *mask = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mask.png"];
 maskLayer.contents = (id)mask.CGImage;
 maskLayer.bounds = (CGRect){CGPointZero, mask.size};

 UIImageView *viewToMask = ;
 viewToMask.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blackandwhite.png"];
 viewToMask.layer.mask = maskLayer;
 [self.view addSubview:viewToMask];
```

Certainly you have to add/remove the mask on touch/release. I leave you with that.

Now what happens when you move your finger? Just move the mask to different positions like so:

```
viewToMask.layer.mask.position = offset position based on touch position
```

I hope I could help you.